# HP Pavilion freezes after boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I have created an ISO image of Ubuntu 18.04 on an USB stick with the burner of Ubuntu 17.10.
When I use the USB stick to boot on a new HP Pavilion G7 running Windows 10 it loads Ubuntu 18.04 and shows a desktop. I can move the cursor but nothing happens when I click on any of the icons.
I have changed the boot options to use legacy and disabled secure boot.
My old Dell can boot from the USB stick without problems.

Answer (score 1):

- After having selected boot from USB UEFI and started the boot process pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> to show the Grub options.
- I edited the line with `quiet splash` by pressing <kbd>E</kbd> to `nomodeset quiet splash`.
- Once Ubuntu was installeded I changed the grub configuration in order to make the changes permanent:

  - editing `/etc/default/grub`: set the line starting with `"GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`
  - run `sudo update-grub`.

See [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu).